# Double Free - crash or no crash

Tags: linux, exploit, c, glibc

Can someone explain me why freeing `a` twice in a row causes a crash, but freeing `a` first, then `b`, and then `a` again does not crash?

I know that a free will insert the heap chunk in a double linked free list. Freeing twice would insert the same chunk twice in the free list. But why is the crash happening?

```
int *a = malloc(8);
int *b = malloc(8);

free(a);

// free(a); // Would crash!

free(b);

free(a); // No crash.
```

Comment: Infosec is probably not the most appropriate forum for this question. Consider StackOverflow.

Comment: Why should it always crash? Even `int a[5]; a[10] = 100;` doesn't always crash.

Comment: Learn what _undefined behaviour_ is. You will eventually  meet it more than once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because in C lingo, **undefined behavior** is just that: undefined. Anything might happen.

Also see `man 3 free`:

> […] if `free(ptr)` has already been called before, undefined behavior occurs.