# Why is the destructor not called for Box::from_raw()?

Tags: rust, smart-pointers, unsafe

I am passing a raw pointer to two different closures and converting the raw pointer to a reference using [`Box::from_raw()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.from_raw) and the program is working fine.

However, after converting the raw pointer to reference, the destructor should be called automatically as the documentation says:

> This function is unsafe because improper use may lead to memory problems. For example, a double-free may occur if the function is called twice on the same raw pointer.

However, I am able to access the reference to ABC even after calling `Box::from_raw()` on raw pointer twice and it's working fine.

```
struct ABC {}

impl ABC {
    pub fn new() -> ABC {
        ABC {}
    }

    pub fn print(&self, x: u32) {
        println!("Inside handle {}", x);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let obj = ABC::new();
    let const_obj: *const ABC = &obj;

    let handle = |x| {
        let abc = unsafe { Box::from_raw(const_obj as *mut ABC) };
        abc.print(x);
    };
    handle(1);

    let handle1 = |x| {
        let abc = unsafe { Box::from_raw(const_obj as *mut ABC) };
        abc.print(x);
    };
    handle1(2);
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=597cfee5bcb409d42f66b81224fa28bf)

Why is the destructor is not called for `ABC` after `handle` and before `handle1` as the [description](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.from_raw) for `Box::from_raw()` function specifies:

> Specifically, the `Box` destructor will call the destructor of `T` and free the allocated memory.

Why is `Box::from_raw()` working multiple times on a raw pointer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR you are doing it wrong.

---

> converting the raw pointer to a reference

No, you are converting it into a `Box`, not a reference.

> the program is working fine

It is not. You are merely being "lucky" that memory unsafety and undefined behavior isn't triggering a crash. This is likely because your type has no actual data.

> to reference, the destructor should be called automatically

No, when *references* go out of scope, the destructor is not executed.

> Why is the destructor is not called

It **is**, which is one of multiple reasons your code is completely and totally broken and unsafe.

Add code to be run during destruction:

```
impl Drop for ABC {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("drop")
    }
}
```

And you will see it is called 3 times:

```
Inside handle 1
drop
Inside handle 2
drop
drop
```

> I am able to access the reference to ABC

Yes, which is unsafe. You are breaking the rules that you are supposed to be upholding when writing `unsafe` code. You've taken a raw pointer, done something to make it invalid, and are then accessing the original, now invalid variable.

The documentation **also** states:

> the only valid pointer to pass to this function is the one taken from another `Box` via the [`Box::into_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw) function.

You are ignoring this aspect as well.

Comment: Why handle1 is not giving an error when the program is using a memory location which has been deallocated using a destructor?

Comment: @Ankit Because *you deliberately used `unsafe` to circumvent the safety features that would issue an error*. There's a reason `Box::from_raw` is an `unsafe fn`; its safety can't be guaranteed at compile time, so it falls on *you*, the programmer, to guarantee you're using it correctly. You're not.

Comment: @Ankit That's not how it works. See also [Double Free - crash or no crash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36682186/155423).

Comment: Why are there two `drop` at the end? One is for `abc` in `handle1` and one for `obj`. Isn't both `abc` and obj are pointing to the same thing?

And will it work if use `let const_obj: *const ABC = &obj;` after `handle(1)`?

Comment: @Ankit you are dropping the same value 3 times. Once each when the result of `from_raw` goes out of scope and once when the variable `obj` goes out of scope. This is another example of introduced undefined behavior.

Comment: @Ankit You are not at any point putting the `ABC` into a `Box<ABC>`, so it can't be correct to call `Box::from_raw`. You should only call `Box::from_raw` when you want the object to be destructed; otherwise, you can just use the raw pointer or convert it to a reference. [Here's a correct, but unidiomatic example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=03ab4fb9e633abfdf2b9e59c32539bfc); one idiomatic way would be to use references, or perhaps [leak it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=92c444dacf6a4e407113be3ff542246d).